# A controls disabled through server side is still enabled in client side why?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

I have a .net control. I am disabling the list items of the controls using the attribute property.
In client side for validation i am checking whether the control is enabled or disabled. 
the j query written still says the controls is enabled even if it is disabled and fires a alert. 
i am kind of struggling anyone can help me please..

here are my code

```
    private void EnableDisableControl(ListControl control, Boolean value)
    {
        if (value == true)
        {
            foreach (ListItem item in control.Items)                {
                item.Attributes.Remove("checked");
                item.Attributes.Add("disabled", "disabled");
            }
        }
        else
        {

            foreach (ListItem item in control.Items)
            {
                item.Attributes.Remove("disabled");

            }
        }

    }
```

i used this function to disabled one of my control

```
    EnableDisableControl(rdb_control, true);
```

here is the jquery

```
   if ($("#<%=rdb_control.ClientID%> input[type='radio']").is(':enabled')) {
                if ($("#<%=rdb_control.ClientID%> input[type='radio']:checked").length == 0) {
       alert("Required");                        
                }

            }
```

Here even the control is disabled i still get the alert. whereas it shouldn't even check if the control is disabled.

Here is the HTML it looks it disables the span

```
   <table id="ctl00_m_g_c09fd465_0ae4_479b_8fc6_21a7de645003_ctl00_rdb_control" class="chklistUnknown" border="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td><span disabled="disabled"><input id="ctl00_m_g_c09fd465_0ae4_479b_8fc6_21a7de645003_ctl00_rdb_control_0" type="radio" name="ctl00$m$g_c09fd465_0ae4_479b_8fc6_21a7de645003$ctl00$rdb_control" value="Yes" /><label for="ctl00_m_g_c09fd465_0ae4_479b_8fc6_21a7de645003_ctl00_rdb_control_0">is</label></span></td>
                    </tr><tr>
                        <td><span disabled="disabled"><input id="ctl00_m_g_c09fd465_0ae4_479b_8fc6_21a7de645003_ctl00_rdb_control_1" type="radio" name="ctl00$m$g_c09fd465_0ae4_479b_8fc6_21a7de645003$ctl00$rdb_control" value="No" /><label for="ctl00_m_g_c09fd465_0ae4_479b_8fc6_21a7de645003_ctl00_rdb_control_1">not</label></span></td>
                    </tr><tr>
                        <td><span disabled="disabled"><input id="ctl00_m_g_c09fd465_0ae4_479b_8fc6_21a7de645003_ctl00_rdb_control_2" type="radio" name="ctl00$m$g_c09fd465_0ae4_479b_8fc6_21a7de645003$ctl00$rdb_control" value="Unknown,Yes" /><label for="ctl00_m_g_c09fd465_0ae4_479b_8fc6_21a7de645003_ctl00_rdb_control_2">Unknown</label></span></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML as it comes from the server? There you can see if your server-side method is working or not. We need this information to find out whether the problem is in the .NET code or the javascript code.

Comment: my server side method is working i see the control with disabled options. but when i click on the submit button it still looks for the controls as enabled and fires alert as it will have nothing checked.

Comment: Still, it would be very useful for us to see that HTML. We cannot know what's wrong otherwise (or at least I can't).

Comment: added the HTML in the question it self

Comment: @user, arbitrary elements cannot be disabled. Only form controls can.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem is in your server-side code. You are disabling the `span` elements, that cannot be disabled. When your jQuery asks whether your `radiobuttons` are enabled, the answer is yes... because they are enabled. No radiobutton has `disabled` attribute.

You've got to change your server method and dig further in the control tree to find and disable the `inputs`, not the `spans`.

The `CheckListControl` has a `Enabled` property. Just set it to `false`:

```
private void EnableDisableControl(ListControl control, Boolean value)
{
    control.Enabled = value;
}
```

It should disable the checkboxes automatically.

Comment: How do you create the `ListControl`? Using the designer? By code?

Comment: that is a asp.net control

Comment: I know, but a ListControl can contain multiple things. How do you add the checkboxes to it?

Comment: this is asp.net checkboxlist control which automatically have checkboxes

Comment: Try the solution I put in my answer

Comment: i don't need to disable the whole control only the checkbox control which value is not "Unknown"

Comment: Mmh, in the code you posted you were trying to disable **all** checkboxes in the control. Anyway, if you only want to diable one checkox I suggest you not to use a predefined `ASP.NET` control. Instead, put yourself the checkboxes with HTML and `Checkbox` controls. Either that or create your own control that inherits from CheckboxListControl